How to create this gradient with two circles overlapping?
I discovered a few free gradients in the Photoshop template library that I would like to reproduce so that I understand the principles behind them. They are from Pixelbuddha Studios and can be seen in detail here: https://stock.adobe.com/templates/gradient-textures-set/514305481.

It looks like there are mainly two circles with gradients on top of each other. That's how I started my attempt, experimented a bit with more layers and layer effects and managed to make it look very similar:

However, it doesn't look as “smooth” and radiant as the original. Am I missing a certain technique or what would be the best approach to create it?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I would suggest this is more complex than you think, possibly involving more than two circular gradients, possibly even using some soft edged brushes as well, and different blending modes, and that this is likely the result of a happy accident. Reproducing it more accurately would involve quite a bit of trial and error.

Hi, thanks for your comment. Ok, maybe I will try something with brushes and gain some more experience with blending modes.
